# Argparse input with spaces and escape characters

Tags: python, parsing, arguments, argparse

The following is my python script

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('query', nargs='*')
args = parser.parse_args() 
print args.query
```

If I rum this with an argument like:

```
python script.py use of \n
```

It gives me the following output:

```
['use', 'of', 'n']
```

whereas I would like to have

```
['use', 'of', '\\n']
```

and so on.

Comment: I get `['use', 'of', '\\n']`.

Comment: oh! that will do. I corrected the question.

Comment: basically I will join the string with spaces so i want it as it is.

Comment: It gives the output You like to have

Comment: no it doesn't. I'm on python27 btw.

Comment: What platform/console? What is `sys.argv` prior to parsing the args?

Comment: Ubuntu. sys.argv is `['script.py', 'use', 'of', 'n']`

Comment: Try running like: `python script.py "use of \n"`, when Argument contains spaces, e.g. a sentence, usually it is passes in quotes or double quotes.

Comment: `argparse` works with what the shell and interpreter give it in `sys.argv`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be getting this behavior on linux where '\' is shell escape character. It is used to continue a long command in next line. So you can write a long command in multi line by using '\' character.
When you run

```
python script.py use of \n
```

shell take '\n' as two char '\' a escape char and 'n', 
Solution should be

```
python script.py use of \\n
```

or

```
python script.py use of '\n'
```

Comment: That doesn't really solve the issue. What about an input like : `ma'am it'll`

Comment: You are running command on shell, You need to write in the way shell interpret it.